# Acceleration of a fixed observer in a Schwarzschildd space-time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, acceleration

Consider an observer at fixed coordinates $(R, \bar \theta, \bar \phi)$ outside the horizon of a Schwarzschild black hole
$$ ds^2 = -\left( 1 - \frac{2m}{r} \right) dt^2 + \left(1- \frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2 + sin^2 \theta d\phi^2) \, .$$
Compute the four-acceleration $a^{\mu} = u^{\nu} \nabla_{\nu} u^{\mu}$ of the observer, where $u^{\mu}$ is the four-velocity.

---

Since the observer is fixed in space, $u = (u^t, 0, 0, 0)$ and 
$$ a^t = u^t ( \partial_t u^t + \Gamma_{tt}^t u^t ) \, ,$$
but $\Gamma_{tt}^t = - \frac 12 g^{tt} \partial_t g_{tt} = 0$.

This is true form the point of view of another observer that look at our friend from infinity (as the Schwarzschild coordinates are defined), but this can't be true in his reference frame.

**Question**: Can I suppose that his radial velocity $u^r$ is the same in magnitude as if he was radially falling, but opposed in verse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the proper acceleration, you need to calculate all the components of the four vector, especially the radial one: (be careful to make a good covariant derivative) $$a^r = u^t(\partial_t u^r + \Gamma^r_{t\alpha}u^\alpha)$$

The proper radial velocity of this observer is 0. The time component can be calculated by making use of the fact that $u_\mu u^\mu = -1$.

Comment: I was erroneously considering that $a^r = u^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} u^r = 0$ since $u^r = 0$ which obviously is a miserable mistake.